# Seaborn PairPlot to plot matrix error of each individual entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have four 5x5 matrices that I want to compare to one "original"-matrix. I calculated the error of each matrix which results in a new 5x5 matrix that has the percentage error for each entry.

e.g.: Matrix_W

```
     Ac   Bc   Cc   Dc   Ec

Ar  0.04 0.03 0.02 0.05 0.06

Br  0.01 0.02 0.04 0.02 0.01

Cr  0.03 0.05 0.09 0.08 0.01

Dr  0.07 0.09 0.05 0.03 0.01

Er  0.01 0.03 0.05 0.05 0.08
```

(r for row, c for column)

I stored four of these matrices in a pandas DataFrame:

```
 Ac   Bc   Cc   Dc   Ec   rowValue   mType
0.04 0.03 0.02 0.05 0.06     Ar       W
0.01 0.02 0.04 0.02 0.01     Br       W
0.03 0.05 0.09 0.08 0.01     Cr       W
0.07 0.09 0.05 0.03 0.01     Dr       W
0.01 0.03 0.05 0.05 0.08     Er       W
0.04 0.04 0.03 0.01 0.02     Ar       X
0.09 0.07 0.05 0.04 0.01     Br       X
0.01 0.02 0.06 0.05 0.07     Cr       X
            ……
0.06 0.08 0.04 0.03 0.09     Er       Z
```

Now, I want to create a 5x5 scatterplot matrix using seaborn to plot the error for each of the four matrices. Similar to this one, just with a 5 columns and rows:

[image]

So cell 0,0 (upper left corner) of the scatterplot matrix should show a plot of the error in position Ac, Ar of the four matrices. The x and y axis of the scatter plot matrix are independent: x_vars = Ac up to Ec; y_vars= Ar up to Er. The `hue` should depend on the `mType` variable.

The following code did not lead to the desired output:

```
Import Seaborn as sns

g = sns.PairGrid(df, x_vars=df.columns[:-2], y_vars=df[‚rowValue‘], hue=df[‚mType‘])
g.map(sns.scatterplot)
```

The result I get is a 20x5 matrix which does not seem to have an independent x and y-axis. I am not sure if the issue is how I store the data in the DataFrame, or if there are other things that I have to do beforehand to achieve the desired result. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you described: in order to plot a scatterplot you need two variables, one for x axis and one for y axis. With your set of data you will get a 5x5 grid of subplots and each subplot will contain 4 points (one for each `mType`), but which other variables determinates the position of this 4 points within that subplot?

---

I suggest you a different approch.
You can plot 4 different 5x5 heatmap, one for each `mType`. Each cell of these heatmaps has a color based on its value.

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from string import ascii_uppercase


# user input
np.random.seed(42)
matrix_size = 5
matrices = ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']


# dataframe creation
n_matrix = len(matrices)
row_labels = [f'{lecter}r' for lecter in ascii_uppercase[:matrix_size]]
col_labels = [f'{lecter}c' for lecter in ascii_uppercase[:matrix_size]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'mType': np.repeat(matrices, matrix_size),
                   'rowValue': n_matrix*row_labels})

for col in col_labels:
    df[col] = 0.05 + 0.01*np.random.randn(matrix_size*n_matrix)


# plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, n_matrix, figsize = (5*n_matrix, 5))

for i, mtype in enumerate(df['mType'].unique(), 0):
    cbar = False if i != n_matrix - 1 else True
    sns.heatmap(ax = ax[i],
                data = df.loc[df['mType'] == mtype, col_labels],
                vmin = 0.02,
                vmax = 0.08,
                annot = True,
                cbar = cbar,
                cmap = 'Spectral_r')
    ax[i].tick_params(left = False, bottom = False)
    ax[i].set_yticklabels(df['rowValue'].unique())
    ax[i].set_title(mtype)

plt.show()
```

The code above is generalized for any number of matrices and any matrix size.
In your case (4 matrices, size 5):

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for your detailed response.